# acquire lock on azure blob storage

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, hadoop2

I am trying to copy data from one azure blob location to another blob location using hadoop distcp command(running this in spark scala). from destination location, users will query the data. during copy transition, if users query the data maybe they will get duplicate data. so, I can acquire lock on azure destination location. is there any fastest way/best way to copy data with transaction.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use **AzCopy**.

1.Copy a single blob from one container to another within the same storage account

```
AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1 /Dest:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2 /SourceKey:key /DestKey:key /Pattern:abc.txt
```

2.Copy a single blob from one storage account to another

```
AzCopy /Source:https://sourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1 /Dest:https://destaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2 /SourceKey:key1 /DestKey:key2 /Pattern:abc.txt
```

3.Copy all blobs in a container to another storage account

```
AzCopy /Source:https://sourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1 
/Dest:https://destaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2 /SourceKey:key1 /DestKey:key2 /S
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#copy-blobs-in-blob-storage).